# jqgrid toggle expanding subgrid with ui effect

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

How can I toggle expanding subgrid in jqgrid using jquery ui effects like [show](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/) and [hide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/)???

Answer (score 0):

Use this and check out

1. subGridRowExpanded: `function(subgrid_id, row_id) {   loadComplete:`
2. `function() {
                $("#grid_"+row_id).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); } }`